# Finding and comparing files in Python

Tags: python, sorting, find, typeerror

I tried to find a file named "url.html" stored in the variable name_c.
If there is more than the same file on my mac, I'll want to see the last modified.
I wrote this:

```
import time
import os
from collections import OrderedDict

home = os.path.expanduser('~/')
name_c = 'url.html'

found = []
time_d = {}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(home):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if not d == '.Trash']
    if name_c in files:
        found.append(root)

if not found:
    path_w = home
else:
    for times in range(0, len(found)):
        time[times] = found[times], os.stat(found[times]).st_mtime
        time = OrderedDict(sorted(time.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
        path_w = time[len(time) - 1][1]
```

The error is

```
time[times] = found[times], os.stat(found[times]).st_mtime
TypeError: 'module' object does not support item assignment
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Do you import `time` anywhere? That would make it a module. Otherwise it's not defined anywhere before you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported the `time` module somewhere (although your code doesn't show it):

```
>>> import time
>>> time[4] = 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: 'module' object does not support item assignment
```

I suspect you meant to use the dictionary `time_d` instead.

Comment: @Leo The main error was that you didn't post the actual code. If you'd tried to reproduce the problem as minimally as possible, before posting, you would have found the error yourself.